# Asterisk act Gateway

Tags: asterisk, elastix

I have an Asterisk Server with 4 port Zapata : Asterisk Version 1.4.21.2

I want to make this server act exactly like a Gateway

I want to send All my Incoming Calls to Another Server and Route all my Outcoming Calls through this server to around the world.

My Asterisk Server with 4 port Zapata : 192.168.1.100

My Elastix 2.5.0 Server with 100 IP Phone Connected : 192.168.1.10

how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

On server with card:

In /etc/asterisk/extensions.conf

```
[from-zaptel]

exten => _X.,Dial(SIP/El2Ast/${EXTEN})
exten => _X.,Hangup()
```

In sip.conf:

```
[Ast2E1]
type=friend
qualify=yes
insecure=port,invite
host=192.168.1.100
context=toEl
disallow=all
allow=alaw
```

In Elastix sip.conf

```
[El2Ast]
type=friend
qualify=yes
insecure=port,invite
host=192.168.1.10
context=from-pstn
disallow=all
allow=alaw
```

Comment: Idea is ok, all configs was bad. Fixed.